# Why two doppler shifts when reflecting from a moving object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, doppler-effect

> A baseball coach uses a radar device to measure the speed of an
>   approaching pitched baseball. This device sends out electromagnetic
>   waves with frequency $f_0$, and then measures the shift in frequency
>   $\Delta f$ of the waves reflected from the moving baseball. If the
>   fractional frequency shift produced by a baseball is $\frac{\Delta
> f}{f_0}=2.86\times10^{-7}$, what is the baseball's speed? (Hint: Are the
>   waves Doppler-shifted a second time when reflected off the ball?)

I know that because the ball has a non-relativistic velocity, there are certain terms of the Doppler effect equation that can be simplified, such that $\frac{\Delta f_0}{f}=\frac{u}{c}$, but I do not understand the relation that exists with the waves reflected in the ball.

The answer to the problem is $u=\frac{\Delta f_0}{2f}(c)=\frac{2.86\times 10^{-7}}{2}(3\times10^8\,{\rm m})=42.9\,{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-1}=154\,{\rm km}\,{\rm h}^{-1}$

Where does the "$2$" in $u=\frac{\Delta f_0}{2f}(c)$ of the answer come from?

Answer (score 2):

Another way of visualizing the need for a factor of two (which amounts to the same thing as the answer of @Now IGet...,):

As far as the Doppler shift is concerned, the ball is, in effect, a plane mirror.  It is forming a virtual image of the radar gun (as a *source*) behind it;  this virtual source has *its* velocity measured by the radar gun. The distance from the ball to the real source always equals the distance from the ball to the virtual source.

When the ball moves a distance $x$ towards the real detector, the virtual detector also moves a distance $x$ towards the ball, or a distance $2x$ towards the real gun.

So, after using the standard Doppler shift equation to find the velocity of the virtual source towards the detector, you need to divide the answer by $2$ to find the velocity of the ball...

Answer (score 0):

There is a factor of two because there are two doppler shifts: one when the ball sees the wave from the coach, and one when the coach sees the waves reflected by the moving ball. The baseball sees a fractional frequency shift of $u/c$ owing to the balls own motion. Let's say for concreteness that the radar gun emitted a flash of light every second, and $u/c$ is $10\%$.  Then the ball sees flashes of light every $0.9$ seconds, since it is moving towards the coach. Therefore the ball is relecting light with a frequency shifted up by $u/c$, so every $0.9$ seconds.

But now the coach is seeing this signal coming from a moving source, so there is another doppler shift owing to the fact that the baseball is a moving source. The fractional shift is again $u/c$, so even though the ball is flashing every $0.9$ seconds, the coach sees  a flash every $0.8$ seconds, so you get a total fractional shift of $2u/c$, so $\Delta f/f_0=2u/c$.